# How can i get phonegap-plugin-push senderID

Tags: php, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

How can i get phonegap-plugin-push senderID

i tried looking on internet but none of them seems to be working , may be google has updated something .

https://console.developers.google.com

have created a new project here .

after i went inside dashboard .
I see the message No APIs or services are enabled .

can anyone please guide .

this is my code where i'm trying to replace my sender id

```
console.log('calling push init');
var push = PushNotification.init({
    "android": {
        "senderID": "XXXXXXXX"
    },
    "browser": {},
    "ios": {
        "sound": true,
        "vibration": true,
        "badge": true
    },
    "windows": {}
});
console.log('after init');

push.on('registration', function(data) {
    console.log('registration event: ' + data.registrationId);

    var oldRegId = localStorage.getItem('registrationId');
    if (oldRegId !== data.registrationId) {
        // Save new registration ID
        localStorage.setItem('registrationId', data.registrationId);
        // Post registrationId to your app server as the value has changed
    }

    var parentElement = document.getElementById('registration');
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.waiting');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
});

push.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("push error = " + e.message);
});

push.on('notification', function(data) {
    console.log('notification event');
    navigator.notification.alert(
        data.message,         // message
        null,                 // callback
        data.title,           // title
        'Ok'                  // buttonName
    );
```

});

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Which phonegap version are you using? Further, which service do you use to send push notificaitons (FCM,Azure,..)?

Comment: @i have used FCM and now push notification working .